# Address a co-workers service request that is not the main priority

Tags: task-management

I have a co-worker that is frequently asking me by e-mail to perform a task that is not my main priority.  I'll be finishing the main task in about two weeks, and I was wondering how could I politely tell him that I'll be working on it as soon as I finish my current task?

Comment: My first question is if this co-worker is supposed to be asking you to perform tasks directly as opposed to going through a work management tool, a team lead, or a supervisor. My second question is if this co-worker is supposed to be going to you to ask for tasks to be done, is email the correct venue to do so?

Comment: Wouldn't you have other tasks to do when your main priority is done?

Comment: "Hi, I most likely don't have time the coming weeks for this.  Please enter your request in our issue tracker so my product owner/boss/whatever can prioritize it correctly.  Thanks"

Comment: If it's a business-related request, you have a process for accepting those; as @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen says, tell them to use that process. If it's entirely personal, then it's your own after-work time and if they want it done they need to wait until you have the time or ask someone else.

Comment: Who decides what tasks you do? Who decided this two weeks task is the main task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I usually reply with:

"Hi *colleague's name*

I'm currently working on *main project* and it requires my entire focus. I will be able to look at this request after *date*.

Once I've completed *main project*, I'll be in touch to commence work on this task.

Thanks
"

Short and sweet - and you've let them know that you'll be in touch with them when you are ready. If they persist - raise it to your manager or whoever sets your work schedule - let them decide. If the co-workers request is critical enough, they may decide to pause your main task so you can get the other out of the way, if not - they can tell them to back off.

Comment: My hesitation is that, even after you finish this task your friend's request may need to be set aside again for other priorities. Better to get it into the official work list, where it can be addressed in priority order... and possibly picked up by someone else before you can get to it (but also possibly deferred indefinitely or rejected if your friend can't make a good case for why this is worth doing).

Answer (score 4):

How much work do these tasks usually take? If it only takes you half an hour or so and looks like it enables your colleague doing their own tasks it may be worthwhile to just quickly squeeze them into your schedule. This only applies if a couple of conditions are satisfied:

- the task is quick to finish
- you can do the task much quicker or much better than your colleague could do it on their own
- having this task finished enables your colleague to do some other tasks they are supposed to do

If these points are all satisfied your direct supervisor should understand that it is in the companies overall best interest for you to help out your colleague. If one of the points is not satisfied or you are not sure about it just run it by your boss first as the other answers suggest as well.

Comment: Like this approach. Choose when to say yes and when to say no. Always yes or always no leads to problems. Just make sure your yes/no is in the best interest of the company and therefore defendable

Answer (score 1):

Reply to the email with the points you raised in the question:

- You are working on a task that is your main priority
- You will finish this task in about two weeks
- You will start his task as soon as you finish yours

In addition, you can state why this task is your main priority.  For example, the project manager assigned it to you as your highest priority.

If he challenges you on your assumption, perhaps you could engage with others on the project to gain consensus.

Also, copy the person (or people) who assigned this task to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would tell your colleague to ask your manager for assistance and see if they can get resources directly.

The colleague is at your level, and most organizations don't expect you to assign work at the same level.

If they keep doing it privately without informing the manager, let your colleague know that they will need to loop in manager's approval before starting the work.